# Existe algum motivo para a tela estar completamente preta no programa kivy?

Tags: python-3.x, python-kivy, kivy

Estou me deparando com um problema bem chato ao tentar rodar o programa. Dei uma olhada em perguntas semelhantes a minha no site, mas não me deram muita luz.
Preciso fazer um trabalho, mas sempre que crio novos arquivos é sempre a mesma coisa.

Quando eu tento rodar o programa ele simplesmente fica preto, e não sei o motivo, pois no console não  mostra ou indica qualquer erro.

Meu código .py é o seguinte:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window

class Quadro(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.size = (500,500)
    
    def criar(self):
        n = self.ids.nome.text
        c = self.ids.cidade.text        
        result = n + " mora em " + c
        self.ids.resultado.text = result

class testeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = "Um App qualquer"
        return Quadro()

meuObj = testeApp()
meuObj.run()
```

E este é meu .kv:

```
<Quadro>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Label:
        text: "digite um nome: "
    TextInput:
        text: ""
        id: nome
    
    Label:
        text: "digite uma cidade"
    TextInput:
        text: ""
        id: cidade
    
    Button:
        text: "gerar frase"
        on_release: root.criar()
    
    Label:
        text: "aguardando resposta..."
        id: resultado
```

Aqui vou mostrar oque aparece no console e na janela do programa:

Este código é basicamente uma réplica do que tive em uma aula(esse programa que tive em aula roda tranquilo), então imploro por alguma ajuda.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei que consegui me achar, encontrei o motivo de ficar preto. Bom explicarei para aqueles que vierem a ter o mesmo problema.

Lá no final, na última classe é necessário que ela tenha o nome do arquivo .kv, no meu caso é exemplo.kv, então deverá ficar como:

```
class exemploApp(App):   #pode ser apenas: exemplo(App)
    def build(self):
        self.title = "Um App qualquer"
        return Quadro()

meuObj = exemploApp()
meuObj.run()
```

Aqui está uma imagem do programa rodando:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]